# Spark: dropping multiple columns using regex

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In a Spark (2.3.0) project using Scala, I would like to `drop` multiple columns using a regex. I tried using [colRegex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@colRegex(colName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), but without success:

```
val df = Seq(("id","a_in","a_out","b_in","b_out"))
  .toDF("id","a_in","a_out","b_in","b_out")

val df_in = df
  .withColumnRenamed("a_in","a")
  .withColumnRenamed("b_in","b")
  .drop(df.colRegex("`.*_(in|out)`"))

// Hoping to get columns Array(id, a, b)
df_in.columns
// Getting Array(id, a, a_out, b, b_out)
```

On the other hand, the mechanism seems to work with `select`:

```
df.select(df.colRegex("`.*_(in|out)`")).columns
// Getting Array(a_in, a_out, b_in, b_out)
```

Several things are not clear to me:

1. what is this backquote syntax in the regex?
2. `colRegex` returns a `Column`: how can it actually represent several columns in the 2nd example?
3. can I combine `drop` and `colRegex` or do I need some workaround?

Comment: You can try something like: df.drop(df.columns.filter(c => c matches regex))  or you can assign filtered list to variable and then use: df.drop(list:_*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check spark code of colRefex method ... it expects regexs to be passed in the below format

```
 /** the column name pattern in quoted regex without qualifier */
 val escapedIdentifier = "`(.+)`".r
 /** the column name pattern in quoted regex with qualifier */
 val qualifiedEscapedIdentifier = ("(.+)" + """.""" + "`(.+)`").r
```

backticks(`) are necessary to enclose your regex, otherwise the above patterns will not identify your input pattern.

you can try selecting specific colums which are valid as mentioned below

```
val df = Seq(("id","a_in","a_out","b_in","b_out"))
  .toDF("id","a_in","a_out","b_in","b_out")

val df_in = df
  .withColumnRenamed("a_in","a")
  .withColumnRenamed("b_in","b")
  .drop(df.colRegex("`.*_(in|out)`"))
val validColumns = df_in.columns.filter(p => p.matches(".*_(in|out)$")).toSeq //select all junk columns
val final_df_in = df_in.drop(validColumns:_*) // this will drop all columns which are not valid as per your criteria.
```

Comment: I just checked the implem (thx for the reminder): is it correct that colRegex would also accept a simple column name as argument, thus the need for backticks in order to suggest regex matching should be used?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the workaround proposed by Waqar Ahmed and kavetiraviteja (accepted answer), here is another possibility based on `select` with some [negative regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) magic. More concise, but harder to read for non-regex-gurus...

```
val df_in = df
  .withColumnRenamed("a_in","a")
  .withColumnRenamed("b_in","b")
  .select(df.colRegex("`^(?!.*_(in|out)_).*$`")) // regex with negative lookahead
```